# Setting font color of JavaFX TableView Cells?

Tags: java, tableview, javafx, textcolor

In my Java Desktop Application I have a JavaFX Table with 3 columns. I want to set the font color of the 3rd column to red. I have not been able to set the font color of the Tableb at all. I looked into CSS and I did not find anything. Is there a way to do it with CSS? I also looked for setFont() with the hope of setting it that way. Nothing there. I could not even figure a way to set something on a certain cell.

```
TableView<TableData> myTable = new TableView<TableData>();
ObservableList<TableData> myTableData = FXCollections.observableArreyList(
    new TableData("data", "data", "data"),
    new TableData("data", "data", "data"));

TableColumn firstColumn = new TableColumn("First Column");
firstColumn.setProperty("one");
TableColumn secondColumn = new TableColumn("Second Column");
secondColumn .setProperty("two");
TableColumn thirdColumn = new TableColumn("Third Column");
thirdColumn .setProperty("three");

myTable.setItems(myTableData);
myTable.getColumns.addAll(firstColumn, secondColumn, thirdColumn);
```

How can I accomplish this? How can I set to font color? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to override the CellFactory.

Partial code just of the third column:

```
    TableColumn thirdColumn = new TableColumn("Third Column");  
    thirdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String>("three"));

    // ** The TableCell class has the method setTextFill(Paint p) that you 
    // ** need to override the text color
    //   To obtain the TableCell we need to replace the Default CellFactory 
    //   with one that returns a new TableCell instance, 
    //   and @Override the updateItem(String item, boolean empty) method.
    //
    thirdColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
        public TableCell call(TableColumn param) {
            return new TableCell<TableData, String>() {

                @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (!isEmpty()) {
                        this.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                        // Get fancy and change color based on data
                        if(item.contains("@")) 
                            this.setTextFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
                        setText(item);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

Entire Code Example:

```
package tablecelltextcolorexample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 *
 * @author jKaufmann
 */
public class TableCellTextColorExample extends Application {
public static class TableData {
    SimpleStringProperty one,two,three;
    public TableData(String one, String two, String three) {
        this.one = new SimpleStringProperty(one);
        this.two = new SimpleStringProperty(two);
        this.three = new SimpleStringProperty(three);
    }
    public String getOne() {
        return one.get();
    }

    public void setOne(String one) {
        this.one.set(one);
    }

    public String getThree() {
        return three.get();
    }

    public void setThree(String three) {
        this.three.set(three);
    }

    public String getTwo() {
        return two.get();
    }

    public void setTwo(String two) {
        this.two.set(two);
    }

} 
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 200, 200);
    stage.setTitle("Table View - Change color of a particular column");
    stage.setWidth(400);
    stage.setHeight(500);


    TableView<TableData> myTable = new TableView<TableData>();
    ObservableList<TableData> myTableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new TableData("data", "data", "data"),
            new TableData("data", "data", "data"),
            new TableData("Name the song","867-5309","SomeEmail@gmail.com"));  

    TableColumn firstColumn = new TableColumn("First Column"); 
    firstColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String>("one"));

    TableColumn secondColumn = new TableColumn("Second Column"); 
    secondColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String>("two"));

    TableColumn thirdColumn = new TableColumn("Third Column");  
    thirdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String>("three"));

    // ** The TableCell class has the method setTextFill(Paint p) that you 
    // ** need to override the text color
    //   To obtain the TableCell we need to replace the Default CellFactory 
    //   with one that returns a new TableCell instance, 
    //   and @Override the updateItem(String item, boolean empty) method.
    //
    thirdColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
        public TableCell call(TableColumn param) {
            return new TableCell<TableData, String>() {

                @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (!isEmpty()) {
                        this.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                        // Get fancy and change color based on data
                        if(item.contains("@")) 
                            this.setTextFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
                        setText(item);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });

    myTable.setItems(myTableData); 
    myTable.getColumns().addAll(firstColumn, secondColumn, thirdColumn);

    vbox.getChildren().addAll(myTable);
    VBox.setVgrow(myTable, Priority.ALWAYS);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I already figured it out. I just did not get the chance to post an answer. But yours is a good answer.

Comment: Thanks! I figured as much from your other posts - but I've seen this question pop up to many times in other places to leave it unanswered.

Comment: Sorry that I'm late to the party, but how do you disable the text fill when the table row is selected? Regards

Comment: And what if after you add a TextFill color, then you want to restore the default colors of the TableView? For example, the cell value changed its content and now it does not contain `"@"`.

Answer (score 7):

I found a CSS code. Apply this `red-column` class into your column.

```
.red-column.table-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0.5em;
    -fx-border-color: transparent -fx-box-border transparent transparent;
    -fx-font: 13px "Arial";
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

Your table will be like this.

[image]

Full css for table-view is [here](https://gist.github.com/PandukaNandara/b0963bf3acb0a1b53aa4a4d52b62aa22).

Answer (score 5):

The Code need to be little changed:

```
// Method for displaying data in table
    protected void displayDataInTable(){
        tblColID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("id"));

        // Table cell coloring
        tblColID.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, String> call(TableColumn<Person, String> param) {
                return new TableCell<Person, String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (!isEmpty()) {
                            this.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                            // Get fancy and change color based on data
                            if(item.contains("@")) 
                                this.setTextFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
                            setText(item);

                        }
                    }

                };
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, similar to Panduka,

```
tableColumn.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red");
```

Answer (score 0):

For a multiline cell :

```
    Callback<TableColumn<MyDTO, String>, TableCell<MyDTO, String>> multilineRedCallback = param -> {
        TableCell<MyDTO, String> cell = new TableCell<MyDTO, String>();
        Text text = new Text();
        cell.setGraphic( text );
        cell.setPrefHeight( Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE );
        text.setFill( Color.RED );
        text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind( cell.widthProperty() );
        text.textProperty().bind( cell.itemProperty() );
        return cell;
    };
    this.colMultilineRed.setCellFactory( multilineRedCallback );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.