# How do I change the font in TableColumn JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

How do I change the font in `TableColumn` JavaFX? I am programming on macOS and faced the problem of incorrect display of text in `TableView` tables.

It looks something like this:

[image]

There are error codes that occur when opening this window.

```
2021-07-18 16:45:28.259 java[39972:22310146] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFNS-Regular", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
2021-07-18 16:45:28.259 java[39972:22310146] CoreText note: Set a breakpoint on CTFontLogSystemFontNameRequest to debug.
2021-07-18 16:45:28.263 java[39972:22310146] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFNS-Regular", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
2021-07-18 16:45:28.557 java[39972:22310214] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFNS-Regular", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
```

Comment: use a custom style/sheet in css

Comment: Check System Preferences > Language & Region.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269446/javafx-tableview-change-font-of-an-column-programmatically-not-css/48270025#48270025

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting font color of JavaFX TableView Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998551/setting-font-color-of-javafx-tableview-cells)