# How to change the color of the placeholder text in JavaFX TableView?

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, placeholder

I believe it is quite simple, though I couldn't figure it out yet:
How do I change the color of the placeholder text in JavaFX TableView?

This is the placeholder text, which is shown if the table is empty:

[image: JavaFX TableView (dark design)]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998551/setting-font-color-of-javafx-tableview-cells ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to solve this.

### Via Css

Consult the [JavaFx Css Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tableview) and there you will see, that a TableView has an internal *placeholder*, that you can address using Css.

If documentation is insufficient or you need to more information about the structure of the Scenegraph, use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to explore.

### Via placeholder node

Consulting the [JavaFx 8 Api documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#placeholderProperty) will reveal, that there is a *placeholder* property, that allows you to set a custom node as placeholder.

### Demo

This demo showcases both approaches:

**TableViewPlaceholderFill.java**:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewPlaceholderFill extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<String> tableViaCss = new TableView<>();
        tableViaCss.getStyleClass().add("my-little-pony");

        TableView<String> tableWithCustomPlaceholder = new TableView<>();
        final Label placeholderLabel = new Label
                ("Hello, Kitty!");
        placeholderLabel.setFont(Font.font("monospace", FontWeight.BLACK, 16));
        placeholderLabel.setTextFill(Color.HOTPINK);
        tableWithCustomPlaceholder.setPlaceholder(new StackPane(placeholderLabel));

        Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(4,tableViaCss,
                tableWithCustomPlaceholder));
        scene.getStylesheets().add(TableViewPlaceholderFill.class
                .getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**application.css**:

```
.my-little-pony {
     -fx-background-color: palevioletred;
 }

 .my-little-pony .placeholder .label {
     -fx-text-fill: linen;
     -fx-font-family: 'serif';
     -fx-font-size: 1.666em;
     -fx-font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Comment: I implemented it using the second approach and it's working fine now, thank you. Just one thing to be careful about: If the placeholder is set programmatically one has to use the right type of node. I initially was using a `Text` node instead of a `Label` and it doesn't work with `Text` (even if addressing `.text` in the CSS).

Comment: `Text` should work fine. Keep in mind, that it inherits form `Shape`, so the property names are different.